# Laravel Auth::check() returns false even after successful login attempt

Tags: laravel, authentication

This is my `AdminAuthenticate.php`

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
      dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());
      return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{     
    return $this->guard('admin')->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );       
}
```

I'm trying to implement customer for Admin. How com `attemptLogin()` return **true**, but Auth check return **false**?

Answer (score 1):

When using the default login system, you are implicitely using the default guard to login. But afterwards, you are checking for successful login on the `admin` guard. So what you want to do is to add a function `guard()` in your `LoginController` that returns the proper guard:

```
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

Do not forget to import the `Auth` facade with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The mistake was that I failed to implement 'extends Authenticable' in Admin model.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to implement 'extends Authenticable' in Admin model.Issue resolved.